# Red Exclamation (!) Mark on my project name in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I imported one project in Eclipse. but it showing me Red exclamation mark next to my project name.i have seen this Question has been asked many times here. I tried some solutions but those answers does not solve my problem. so i decided to post the Question.

Following warnings in console:

[2014-09-04 01:28:17 - Todo] Project has no project.properties file!     Edit the project properties to set one.
[2014-09-04 01:28:23 - Todo] Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
[2014-09-04 01:29:25 - Todo] Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.

After trying some solution More Errors:

Error executing aapt: Return code -1073741819       Todo        line 1  Android ADT Problem
Project 'Todo' is missing required library: 'C:\Users\sunny\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140624\sdk\platforms\android-20\android.jar'

Comment: The project that you have imported might don't have a project.propreties file so you have firstly to create a new project and then copy the manifest , the src folder and the res folder to this project and it will be well

Comment: Thanks for your response. i tried this but doesn't solve the issue..:(

Comment: attach screen shot of build path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think This is The Problem with your project import.

I have the same issue and i solved it by import my project with some other technique.

**You can Try This:**

save your project(Which you want to import) in your workspace
Now in your eclipse IDE..go to File-->New--> Android Project..
Here you name your project same as that project which you want to import. And Eclipse will Automatically import that project.:)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Right-click your project and click "Android Tools" -> "Fix Project Properties" 
  If that didn't help, right-click your project and click "Properties" -> Java Compiler and check "Enable Project Specific Settings" and in "Compiler Compliance Settings" select 1.5 or 1.6

Comment: Thanks for your ans bro, i tried this but doesn't solve the issue.:(

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a build target selected (right click in project, properties, android) - there need to be a checkmark on a API. If it isn't possible to select a target:
Check if there really is no project.properties file. If there is none, create a empty project.properties in the project root folder. Open Properties, Android, set the target and refresh the project.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you have some missing files in the Android Repo.

I would try and remove the latest ADT from your system and attempt to re-install it. This is done through the Android SDK manager.

Hope this helps :)